# What's the ratio between the segments $\frac{AF.BG}{FG}$ in the figure below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the figure below the trapezoid has height $13$ and is inscribed in a circle of radius $15$. Point $E$ is on the minor arc determined by $A$ and $B$, the points $F$ and $G$ intersect with $ED$, $E$C and $AB$. Then the ratio between the segments $\frac{AF \times BG}{FG}$ is?
[image]

My progress:
I'm lost in this question...Perhaps using some of the segment $AB$ ratio with the diameter $DC$ ??

$\triangle EFG\sim HJC: \frac{JC}{FG} = \frac{JH}{FE}=\frac{HC}{EG}\\
\triangle BJG \sim \triangle HJC: \frac{JC}{JG}=\frac{JH}{BJ}=\frac{HC}{BG}\\
\triangle KID \sim \triangle KAF: \frac{JC}{FK}=\frac{JH}{AF}=\frac{HC}{AK}$

...???
[image]

Comment: is the answer $17-2\sqrt{14}$?

Comment: @DavidQuinn  By Geogebra the answer is $7,52$

Comment: Is E anywhere on the arc AB? and do you get the same answer if you move E to another position?

Comment: @DavidQuinn....yes..the value is constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you see that  $~\triangle AFE \sim  \triangle CBE~$ and $~\triangle BGE \sim \triangle DAE~$?

That leads to
$~ \displaystyle \frac{BC}{AF} = \frac{CE}{AE}~,  \frac{AD}{BG} = \frac{AE}{GE}$

Multiplying, $\displaystyle \frac{BC \times AD}{AF \times BG} = \frac{CE}{GE} \tag1$

As $ \displaystyle \triangle FEG \sim \triangle DEC, ~\frac{CE}{GE} = \frac{CD}{FG}$

Plugging into $(1)$,

$\displaystyle \frac{AF \times BG}{FG} = \frac{BC \times AD}{CD}$

As it is a cyclic trapezium, it must be isosceles and $BC = AD$. Applying Pythagoras,

$OH^2 = OB^2 - BH^2 = 15^2 - 13^2 = 56$

So, $CH = 15 - \sqrt{56}$

$BC \times AD = BC^2 = BH^2 + CH^2 = 13^2 + (15 - \sqrt{56})^2 = 30 (15 - 2 \sqrt{14})$

So the answer is $~(15 - 2 \sqrt{14})$

Comment: excellent..gratitude

Comment: @petaarantes you are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

---

Notice that points $H$ and $I$ in this answer are different from those in the original post.

Let $\frac{AF\cdot BG}{FG}=R$. First of all, $$AB=AF+FG+BG=2\sqrt{15^2-13^2}=4\sqrt{14}$$

Power of a point gives us
\begin{align*}
AF\cdot FB&=AF\cdot\left(4\sqrt{14}-AF\right)=EF\cdot DF&&(1)\\
BG\cdot AG&=BG\cdot\left(4\sqrt{14}-BG\right)=EG\cdot GC&&(2)
\end{align*}
and it follows that
\begin{align*}
\frac{(1)\cdot(2)}{FG^2}\implies R\left(4\sqrt{14}+R\right)=\frac{EF}{FG}\cdot \frac{EG}{FG}\cdot DF\cdot GC
\end{align*}

Now, with $\triangle EFG\sim\triangle HDF$ we have $\frac{EF}{FG}=\frac{HD}{DF}$. Similarly, with $\triangle EFG\sim\triangle IGC$ we have $\frac{EG}{FG}=\frac{IC}{GC}$. Therefore, $$R\left(4\sqrt{14}+R\right)=HD\cdot IC$$

Since $\triangle HDF\sim\triangle IGC$, it follows that $$HD\cdot IC=HF\cdot IG=13^2=169$$ and we finally have the quadratic equation $$R^2+4\sqrt{14}R-169=0$$ whose solutions are $$R=-2\sqrt{14}\pm15$$
We'll take $\color{blue}{R=-2\sqrt{14}+15}$ since $R>0$.

---

Maybe there are solutions that are more straightforward or concise, but I'm just gonna put my answer out here. I believe $R=-2\sqrt{14}+15$ is the correct answer since I've verified it on GeoGebra. Some lengthy brute-force simplifications are skipped in this answer.

Comment: Power of a point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point

Comment: Thanks for help